# How to Use A Different GetEnumerator() in For Each Statement

Tags: vb.net, types, foreach, ienumerable, enumerator

My custom collection `Example` implements `IEnumerable(Of Long)` and `IDictionary(Of String, Long)`.

When I enumerate through my collection with `For Each`, I get values of type `KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)`, but I want values of type `Long`.

The three GetEnumerator's **only** differ in their return type.  This is not overloading.

```
Module Main
    Sub Main()
        Dim Examples As New Example

        For Each E In Examples
            ' E is of type KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)
            ' I want E to be of type Long
        Next
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class Example
    Implements IEnumerable(Of Long), IDictionary(Of String, Long)

    Private Property TheKeyedCollection As KeyedCollection(Of String, Long)

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)) Implements IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)).GetEnumerator
        Return TheKeyedCollection.GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Public Function GetEnumerator1() As IEnumerator(Of Long) Implements IEnumerable(Of Long).GetEnumerator
        Return TheKeyedCollection.GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Public Function GetEnumerator2() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return TheKeyedCollection.GetEnumerator()
    End Function


    '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> IGNORE THESE OTHER UNNECESSARY FUNCTIONS <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Private Sub Add(item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)) Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)).Add
    End Sub
    Private Sub Clear() Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)).Clear
    End Sub
    Private Function Contains(item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)).Contains
        Throw New Exception
    End Function
    Private Sub CopyTo(array() As KeyValuePair(Of String, Long), arrayIndex As Integer) Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)).CopyTo
    End Sub
    Private ReadOnly Property Count As Integer Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)).Count
        Get
            Throw New Exception
        End Get
    End Property
    Private ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)).IsReadOnly
        Get
            Throw New Exception
        End Get
    End Property
    Private Function Remove(item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Long)).Remove
        Throw New Exception
    End Function
    Private Sub Add1(key As String, value As Long) Implements IDictionary(Of String, Long).Add
    End Sub
    Private Function ContainsKey(key As String) As Boolean Implements IDictionary(Of String, Long).ContainsKey
    End Function
    '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> IGNORE THESE OTHER UNNECESSARY FUNCTIONS <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Private Property Item(key As String) As Long Implements IDictionary(Of String, Long).Item
        Get
            Throw New Exception
        End Get
        Set(value As Long)
        End Set
    End Property
    Private ReadOnly Property Keys As ICollection(Of String) Implements IDictionary(Of String, Long).Keys
        Get
            Throw New Exception
        End Get
    End Property
    Private Function Remove1(key As String) As Boolean Implements IDictionary(Of String, Long).Remove
        Throw New Exception
    End Function
    Private Function TryGetValue(key As String, ByRef value As Long) As Boolean Implements IDictionary(Of String, Long).TryGetValue
        Throw New Exception
    End Function
    Private ReadOnly Property Values As ICollection(Of Long) Implements IDictionary(Of String, Long).Values
        Get
            Throw New Exception
        End Get
    End Property
    '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> IGNORE THESE OTHER UNNECESSARY FUNCTIONS <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
End Class
```

I tried setting `GetEnumerator()` and `GetEnumerator2()` to private, but that produced the error: `'For Each' on type 'Example.Example' is ambiguous because the type implements multiple instantiations of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Long)'.`

**How do I pick which `GetEnumerator()` `For Each` uses?**

Answer (score 1):

**Change the name of the function you want as the default enumerator to `GetEnumerator()`.  Not `GetEnumerator1()`.**

If you don't plan to use the other two versions of GetEnumerator, you can set them to `Private`, but they still have to be there to satisfy the given interface.

If you want to use one of the GetEnumerator()s that is not the default, i.e. `GetEnumerator1()`, you need to force `For Each` to infer it like this:

```
For Each E In DirectCast(Example, IEnumerable(Of String))
    ' E is of type String
Next
```